# SimpleDateFormat игнорирует DateFormatSymbols

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, дата

Здравствуйте, есть код:

```
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMM",ruMonthFormatSymbols);    
mCalendarDateDisplay.setText(sdf.format(currentDate.getTime()));
```

...

```
private static DateFormatSymbols ruMonthFormatSymbols = new DateFormatSymbols() {

    @Override
    public String[] getMonths() {
        return new String[]{"Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь",
                "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"};
    }

};
```

Мне нужно отображение месяцев именно в таком виде - с большой буквы и в родительном падеже.

Но в итоге текст в

```
 mCalendarDateDisplay
```

вот такой: "06 августа", а мне нужно "06 Август".

Даже если я явно напишу:

```
 sdf.setDateFormatSymbols(ruMonthFormatSymbols);
```

`SimpleDateFormat` все равно игнорирует мои указания, как исправить?
Спасибо.

Comment: попробуйте "LLLLL" вместо "MMMMM", возможно даже `ruMonthFormatSymbols` не понадобится/

Comment: @zRrr спасибо вам большое. К сожалению в официальной документации не нашел упоминания этого паттерна, но он работает.

Comment: я его тоже не нашел, хотя еще полгода назад он там был. В API 24 интегрировали ICU4J и добавили [andoid.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), возможно связано

Answer (score 2):

В моем случае следует использовать LLLLL,
этот код дал нужный результат

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd LLLLL");
mEditText.setText(sdf.format(currentDate.getTime()));
```